# Gnu Assembler: Evaluate symbols in macro arguments?

Tags: macros, gnu-assembler

In GNU assembler (v. 2.31.1) I would like to pass symbols as set by .equ (or .set) to macros.
As an example on ARM, I would like to convert integer symbols to strings:

```
.equ WIDTH, 100

.macro numToString label, num
\label :
.asciz "\num"
.equ \label\()Len, .-\label
.endm

numToString xyzWidthStr, WIDTH
```

However, this results in a label "xyzWidthStr" for the null-terminated string "WIDTH" instead of "100". Is there a way to force the macro to evaluate/substitute an argument before it is used?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to force the macro to evaluate/substitute an argument before it is used?

You could use the C preprocessor to resolve it when you

`#define WIDTH 100`

Assemble with arm-gcc (not `arm-as`).  gcc will call the C preprocessor for the file before assembling it if the file extension is `.S` or `.sx`.  If you use a different extension, you can

`arm-gcc -x assembler-with-cpp code.asm <options>`

If you want to see the intermediate, pre-processed code, add `-save-temps` to `<options>`.  gcc will save it to `code.s`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am aware of CPP or M4, but I was in particular interested if GAS macros could be written in this way.

Comment: If you prefer gas macros then define WIDTH as a .macro?

Comment: How would the "call" to numToString look like then? If that would be really the only way, I will accept the answer in the sense of that it is impossible to use GAS macros with .equ in the way I intended to do.